# JSF and Thymeleaf together in the same spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, thymeleaf

Started from this jsf and spring-boot project: https://github.com/xtremebiker/jsf-spring-boot
and tried to add **an working project** I've started in Thymeleaf so the jsf servlet should serve *.xhtml resources and spring & Thymeleaf servlet should serve the other urls. But for some reason I can't make it , it only serves *.xhtml resources (jsf) and just throws 404 Not found for anything else.
What should I add so the spring-boot dispatcher servlet should start serve for the different urls? Is this possible?
(spring-boot 2.3.7, jsf 2.3)